# PowerBI DAX – subquery to the same table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table, let's call it `Products` with columns:

- `Id`
- `ProductId`
- `Version`
- *some other columns*…

`Id` column is the primary key, and `ProductId` groups rows. Now I want to view distinct values of `ProductId` where `Version` is highest.

I.e. From data set:
`Id` | `ProductId` | `Version` | ...
`100` | `1` | `0` | ...
`101` | `2` | `0` | ...
`102` | `2` | `1` | ...
`103` | `2` | `2` | ...

I need to get:
`Id` | `ProductId` | `Version` | ...
`100` | `1` | `0` | ...
`103` | `2` | `2` | ...

In SQL I would write:

```
SELECT Id, ProductId, Version, OtherColumns
FROM Products p1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 
 FROM Products p2
 WHERE p2.ProductId = p1.ProductId
 AND p2.Version > p1.Version)
```

But I have no idea how to express this in DAX. Is this approach with subqueries inapplicable in PowerBI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach is to first construct a virtual table of product_ids and their latest versions, and then use this table to filter the original table:

```
EVALUATE 
VAR Latest_Product_Versions = 
      ADDCOLUMNS(
         VALUES('Product'[Product_Id]),
         "Latest Version", CALCULATE(MAX('Product'[Version])))

RETURN 
CALCULATETABLE(
    'Product', 
    TREATAS(Latest_Product_Versions, 'Product'[Product_Id], 'Product'[Version]))
```

Result:

[image]

The benefit of this approach is optimal query execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS` to group `ProductId` and `MAX` `Version`.

Then use `ADDCOLUMNS` to add the corresponding `Id` number(s), using a filter on the `Products` table for the matching `ProductId` and `Version`. I've used `CONCATENATEX` here, so that if multiple `Id` values have the same `Product` / `MAX` `Version` combination, all `Id` values will be returned, as a list.

```
EVALUATE 
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS ( 
            Products[ProductId],
            "@Max Version",
            MAX ( Products[Version] )
        ),
        "@Max Version Id",
        CONCATENATEX ( 
            FILTER ( 
                Products,
                Products[Version] = [@Max Version] && Products[ProductId] = EARLIER ( Products[ProductId] )
            ),
            Products[Id],
            ","
        )
    )
```