# DAX : SELECTCOLUMNS equivalent to a SQL SUBSELECT?

Tags: sql, subquery, dax

I need a help on my DAX Query. Below is my query that I'm using on a Tabular Model to pull Cost Center data. It's working perfectly.

```
EVALUATE (

DISTINCT(

FILTER(
SELECTCOLUMNS(
'dimensionCostCenter',
"Cost Center Code",'dimensionCostCenter'[Cost Center Code],
"Cost Center Name",'dimensionCostCenter'[Cost Center Name],
"Division Name",'dimensionCostCenter'[Division Name],
"Profit Center",'dimensionCostCenter'[Profit Center],
"Cost Center Roll Up L1 Name",'dimensionCostCenter'[Cost Center Roll Up L1 Name])
,NOT ([Cost Center Code]) IN {"211189","211193"})
)

)
```

My challenge is, somehow, to pull just one column, which would be the equivalent of a subselect in SQL.
I applied a pre-filter, to bring only the necessary codes. I'll still need to apply some more filters with the other columns, that's why I'm keeping these columns in the initial query.

But my expectation will be just bring in the "final select" only the Cost Center Code.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: There's no any SQL code to look like. And what is *one column*? Please edit your question and provide more details.

Comment: Hi @astentx, I have already provide this detail on here: But my expectation will be just bring in the "final select" only the Cost Center Code.

Comment: How about this question: [PowerBI DAX – subquery to the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59748337/powerbi-dax-subquery-to-the-same-table)? Add `RETURN` at the end.